# What kind of LEGO are these?

Tags: part-identification, piece-information

Can somebody tell me what are these round heads and these strange cars?  I bought these from a bazaar. The heads are round. There weren't any bodies, just heads. The cars are strange. Looks like from ninja. They look like they won't be LEGO.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

These parts were used in large figures as a part of LEGO [Knights Kingdom II sets](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogList.asp?catType=S&catString=9.536).

"Strange cars" are actually torso/body piece used for these figures.

As an example [Large Figure Torso KK with Santis Pattern - Series 1](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?id=48895)

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, I am feeling know stupid

Comment: @SauleUrbo Don't feel stupid, nobody is expected to know about all the obscure themes LEGO has branched out across it's decades-long history. And I personally find your observation that the body pieces look like fancy Ninjago cars exemplarily creative :)

Comment: I agreed with the probably-not-LEGO idea enough that I added the clone-brands tag to this question.  I've since removed it since Alex has shown we both jumped to the wrong conclusion.  Good times.

Answer (score 1):

There are also some Bionicle masks among the parts, e.g.

[Bionicle Mask Kakama Nuva](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=43615&name=Bionicle%20Mask%20Kakama%20Nuva&category=%5BBionicle,%20Kanohi%20Mask%5D#T=C.) 
and a [Bionicle Shoulder Armor](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=x345&name=Bionicle%20Shoulder%20Armor&category=%5BBionicle%5D#T=C)

Comment: Thank you for formatting, @Syberion!